# In Lotus Notes, how can I add a Database to the 'Replication and Sync' Tab and launch the background replicator on the Notes Client via LotusScript?

Tags: vba, client-side, database-replication, lotusscript

I want to be able to programmatically add Database(s) to the *Replication and Sync* tab in the Notes Client and then run the **background** replicator on the Notes Client.

Appreciate any ideas, I have scoured the web, to no end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the database to the replicator tab can be simply done with the replicate- method of the notesdatabase- class or via NotesUiWorkspace- methods. For the second suggestion you can find an example [here](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/answer/Setting-up-local-replication-of-a-Lotus-Notes-database-for-offline-employees).

Unfortunately you can not start background replication with LotusScript, you have to wait for it to occur.